# Performing multiple regression of time series data using R?

Tags: r, modis, statistics, regression

I am working with MODIS time series data, and I want to stack a stack object to prepare my data for multiple regression.

I have AMSR (soil moisture) as a response variable and I have some explanatory variables such as NDVI and LST and Albedo for a period of 6 months (183 images for each variable).

I want to perform multiple regression analysis between these variables. For a one particular day I can easily use “stack” command to stack the variables for one day and then create data.frame from the stack object, but to apply to the all-time series data I could not find a solution. I guess I should stack the `list.files` for each variable first, and then stack the stack objects again.

However, this has not worked.

Comment: You should be able to stack multiple `RasterStack` objects. Are you getting a warning when attempting to stack them? If so, will you share it? I don't want to jump to assumptions, but the most common error you will run into is misaligned pixels or differing extents. If this is the case, you will first have to run `raster::resample()` and `raster::crop()`.